# Conflict when using constraint with Segment

Tags: ios, constraints

So I'm adding segment into the storyboard and using Add Missing constraint when I run into this problem.

[image: App Screenshot]

And this very complicated (for me) error:

```
2015-01-29 22:29:16.151 MafiaPhone[45162:1236769] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9e397572b0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e39627f00(64)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9e3975cbb0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e39627f00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7f9e39627e30 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9e39748a80 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e396286b0(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7f9e3972bc70 _UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e396286b0.bottom == UIView:0x7f9e39627e30.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39732f20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e39627f00]-(106)-[UITextField:0x7f9e39628e00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e3974bb80 V:[UILabel:0x7f9e397528a0'Role Name']-(29)-[UILabel:0x7f9e3970c3e0'Side']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e3971d360 UILabel:0x7f9e3970c3e0'Side'.lastBaseline == UISegmentedControl:0x7f9e39749690.firstBaseline>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39747ac0 UILabel:0x7f9e397528a0'Role Name'.lastBaseline == UITextField:0x7f9e39628e00.firstBaseline>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39747b10 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7f9e39749690]-(37)-[UIButton:0x7f9e39737e20'Add']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39754070 UIButton:0x7f9e39737e20'Add'.centerY == UIView:0x7f9e39627e30.centerY>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e397540c0 V:[UIButton:0x7f9e39737e20'Add']-(241)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7f9e396286b0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39754160 UISegmentedControl:0x7f9e39749690.lastBaseline == UILabel:0x7f9e3970c3e0'Side'.firstBaseline>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39754200 UISegmentedControl:0x7f9e39749690.lastBaseline == UILabel:0x7f9e3970c3e0'Side'.lastBaseline>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39754250 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7f9e39749690(28)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e39521a20 h=--& v=--& UISegment:0x7f9e3972eef0.midY == + 14.5>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e3951a7a0 UISegmentLabel:0x7f9e39732a30'Second'.centerY == UISegment:0x7f9e3972eef0.centerY>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e3954b6d0 V:|-(6)-[_UIBaselineLayoutStrut:0x7f9e39760330]   (Names: '|':UITextField:0x7f9e39628e00 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9e3951a7a0 UISegmentLabel:0x7f9e39732a30'Second'.centerY == UISegment:0x7f9e3972eef0.centerY>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Segment is the only part that has wrong show up place. Here is the constrain option.

[image: Constrain Option]

My question is:
1. What does the error mean?
2. How to fix this problem?
3. Is using the "Add missing constraints" is the correct thing to do (so far it's the only thing I do to make the run view looks exactly like the storyboard view)? Why?

Thanks for reading the whole long post. Hope you can help me with this frustrating error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your system has too many constraints. The "Add" button has a centerY constraint, and constraints that fix it to views above it, and the bottom layout guide. It's hard to know which constraints you want. I would delete the one between the "Add" button and the bottom layout guide, and also the one between the text field and the navigation bar.

You really shouldn't setup constraints on a complex set of view by using "add missing constraints". Add the ones you need explicitly. If you don't know how to do that, then watch the videos from the 2012 WWDC about Auto Layout.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check the video one :).